# Webpack vendor library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-2

I'm using Webpack 2 to automate my workflow. At the bottom of my index.html are tags:

```
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

vendor.js contains Vue and Axios, but when I'm trying to use Vue in scripts.js there is an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you paste the JavaScript code where you are trying to reference and use Vue?

Comment: It's inside scripts.js: new Vue({ el: '#root' });

Answer (score 0):

You need to implicitly import Vue package, where you use it.
So basically you need to write `import Vue from 'vue';`
However, you may have some specific issue, so you should add a reference code.